# Regex validation taking too long c#

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I have a scenario to use regex for validation.

Here is text format which I need to validate is something like below:

**Valid Text**

> name test +company abc def +phone 3434 +vehicle test + interested yyy +invited zzz

**Invalid Text:**

> name te%st +company +phone 3434 +vehicle test + interested yyy +invited zzz

### Rules

1. There should not be any other character in the text like % in above.
2. Also the first word must follow a space and then there should be some text after that and then the + sign.

Here is regular expression which I wrote:

```
^(([a-z]*[A-Z]*\s?)+(\w*\s*)*\+)*$
```

The problem I am facing is that when text is valid `Regex.Match(text)` returns true immediately. But when I add some other character inside the text which is not valid it takes too long and debugger never returns.

Comment: Nested quantifiers where sequences of optional patterns are quantified always cause catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Probably a back-tracking issue.

Comment: does backtracking occur when text is not valid? Why isn't it taking long when text is valid?

Comment: It is trying to find a single combination of all quantifiers and optional parts that is still valid.

Comment: It's basically doing a huge number of what-ifs, "what if this optional part is not there, but I have multiple of this", etc.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen can you please provide a better regex than this?

Comment: Will need to look at some sample data that you are trying to match.

Comment: Why not just split on "+" and then maybe a trim on each element.

Comment: @thehennyy basically I want to extract key value pair from those + split elements.
They will be made from first alphabet string till space and then value after that space

Comment: You can do whatever check you like after the split. trim was just an example. It seems like you want to check for alphanumeric characters afterwards. Have a look at this: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoIgBgAIiyA6AGQEs8BHAbmrsZkUfKvxK0xAZnoBvavQWMSJWfMXqAbgEMo9BPQC89AER4tAWxj0MMAM4Z6AakjmADlrwBPeluBh6ACYwAGZOrgAWEHhWkiixThow4exgADZWNvZO9Jw2sPYwAfSeJU6cGuw2RQBetcYi6uoIzADKrqmVABQA5I7dAJStMOlgGJ3eBgB8xa3tXd303Wj0JMstGFCcAOZtHRgA8q4Y7FG2zABKMOYQiQCibhiet3gb7HaDLcMwo53VhtPVZgAFU25k6/UGQIgAEEoFAtJ5wZCIBx7ODmABJPC2VzfMb9BqKAC+1CJQA

Answer (score 1):

> is not valid it takes too long and debugger never returns.

You are asking the parser to consider too many scenarios and it has to eliminate all of them before returning; hence the slowness.

---

**Suggestion**

Usage of `*` which means *zero or more occurrences* makes the regex parser *re-think* (backtrack) about **other** possible matches.

Think in terms of chess, there are literally millions of possible combinations. Using the `*` is like saying give me every move possible. But we only want the moves which are pertinent...same is true with regex pattern smithing; keep it to the minimums.

1. With the `*`, instead prefer to use the `+` if you truly know there will be 1 or more of the items and not zero. It keeps the *backtracking* to a minimum and makes for quicker parsing.
2. For your failure scenarions, instead of trying to match the world, why not fail a match by checking for invalids first? This can be done such as `^(?! )` pattern. So, your rule mentioned a failure for non characters found, so put this in first `^(?!.+%)`. That says if there is a `%` *somewhere* in the text, then fail the match.
3. Once #2 is done then just focus on a valid pattern(s) which give the best case scenario.

---

Your example data is problematic, but the in the *spirit* of what you want as a jumping off point I would begin with this pattern:

`^(?!.+%)(\w+\s\w+\s\+\w+\s?)+`

Which says fail on a `%`, then there should be 1 or more of a pattern (word space word space `+`word and possible space)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to come up with a "works always regex", why don't you rephrase the solution without regular expressions at all.

```
var text = "name test +company abc def +phone 3434 +vehicle test + interested yyy +invited zzz";
var parts = text.Split('+');
var matches = parts.All(p => 
{
   var kvp = p.Trim().Split(' ');
   if( kvp.Length != 2 )
       return false;
   return kvp[0].All(char.IsLetter) && kvp[1].All(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
});
```

Although this will cause too many allocations if you want to process large amounts of text but should be good otherwise.

Comment: Your regex is still fraught with catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: No doubt it is, but without looking at more sample data I can't come up with anything better looking.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I have updated the question. Please see

Comment: I have updated the answer based on new information. This should validate the text according to the rules you specified. Should be easy enough to take it forward to actually get access to the kvp once it validates.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple parser? Split on the `'+'` character, then evaluate each phrase. I'm assuming the first word before the space is the key, and the remainder is the value. There's also a regex that checks for valid characters; non-alphanumeric will throw an exception.

```cs
var working = "name test +company abc def +phone 3434 +vehicle test + interested yyy +invited zzz";

if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(working, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 +]"))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

var values = working.Split('+').Select(x => x?.Trim() ?? string.Empty);

foreach (var phrase in values)
{
    string left, right;

    var space = phrase.IndexOf(' ');
    if (space > 0)
    {
        left = phrase.Substring(0, space)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
        right = phrase.Substring(space + 1, phrase.Length - space - 1)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;

        Console.WriteLine("left: [" + left + "], right: [" + right + "]");
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
left: [name], right: [test]
left: [company], right: [abc def]
left: [phone], right: [3434]
left: [vehicle], right: [test]
left: [interested], right: [yyy]
left: [invited], right: [zzz]
```

Running the above with an invalid character throws an exception:

```cs
var working = "na%me test +company abc def +phone 3434 +vehicle test + interested yyy +invited zzz";  

...

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```